# Add en extra property to a random class in generic way

Tags: c#, inheritance

Imagine I have this class

```cs
public MyClass
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

I have an api client that returns me this object like this with an extra property called Capitalized which capitalized all string properties for exemple.

```cs
public MyResult : MyClass
{
    public MyClass Capitalized { get; set; }
}
```

Then I can access things like this :

```cs
MyResult result = /* call to api with my class */
Console.WriteLine(result.FullName);
Console.WriteLine(result.Capitalized.FullName);
```

Is there a way to define a generic MyResult like this, because T can be MyClass, YourClass and the response will always be like :

```cs
public MyResult<T> : T
{
    public T Capitalized { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT : thanks to @Maruf reply
Eric Lippert explains it here why it is impossible : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5890813/1026105

Comment: probably helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5890813/17612995

Comment: Doesn't each `MyClass`, `YourClass` etcetera already have to declare its own properties, regardless of how the API is filling it? Why wouldn't it then also include the `Capitalized` property? Abstracting over the fact that each of the classes has a `Capitalized` would be possible with an interface (`interface ICapitalizable<T> { T Capitalized { get; set; } }`), it's just not particularly useful since you can't use `Capitalized` meaningfully without knowing the type.

Comment: Ultimately it reads like you're better off changing the way the API result is deserialized: return what's in `Capitalized` instead as the base type, and let go of storing both un-capitalized and capitalized data in the same instance (or create a new wrapper type for that, e.g. `record Result<T>(T Uncapitalized, T Capitalized)`).

Answer (score 0):

How about that:

```
public class MyResult<T> : MyClass where T : MyClass
{
    public T Capitalized { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This would not allow you to access the un-capitalized properties of `T = YourClass`. `MyClass` would necessarily need to be a pretty generic base.