# What is the equivalent of a template class in C# that inherits from the specified type?

Tags: c#, c++, templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why cannot C# generics derive from one of the generic type parameters like they can in C++ templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842636/why-cannot-c-sharp-generics-derive-from-one-of-the-generic-type-parameters-like)
>   [Generic class that inherits its generic type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895363/generic-class-that-inherits-its-generic-type)

I would like to be able to do something like this, only in C#:

```
template<class MyClass>
class MockComposite : MyClass
{

};
```

The class above inherits from the specified type. MyClass is a base type, and this is the reason I want this behaviour. I want to be able to instantiate this object with classes derived from MyClass.

I understand you cannot use templates in C#, but is there any way to get the behaviour I want without having to write a new class for each different type of object?

EDIT - I want to be able to instantiate an object that will test the behaviour of any class, as long as that class is derived from a specified type - 'MyClass'.

Comment: @delnan I want to do it in C#

Comment: @SirYakalot: Please describe what you want to achieve with this construct

Comment: This reminds me of the [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), but why would you want to do it in C#?

Answer (score 1):

In C# you have the concept of generics. The following code is equivalent to your C++ code:

```
class MockComposite<T> : T
    where T : MyClass
{
}
```

Unfortunatelly, it is invalid. You will get the following compile error:

> Cannot derive from 'T' because it is a type parameter

In C# you would usually solve this problem with *composition* instead of *inheritance*.

Composition in this case means one of two things:

1. Your class still has the generic argument but doesn't try to derive from it. Furthermore, it has the `new` constraint, meaning that the generic argument needs to have a default constructor:

   ```
   class MockComposite<T>
       where T : MyClass, new()
   {
       T _toTest;

       public MockComposite()
       {
           _toTest = new T();
       }
   }
   ```

   This means you can instantiate the mock class like this: `var mock = new MockComposite<ClassA>();` without the need for creating an instance of `ClassA` outside of the mock class.

   ```
   class MockComposite
   {
       MyClass _toTest;

       public MockComposite(MyClass toTest)
       {
           _toTest = toTest;
       }
   }
   ```

   This means you have to instantiate the mock class like this: `var mock = new MockComposite(new ClassA());`

Comment: @exacerbatedexpert: Maybe you want to read the whole answer. The C++ code translated to C# generic syntax is the code I posted. BTW: 2 downvotes? Do you have multiple accounts?

Answer (score 0):

This is simply not possible in C#. But this is a case of trying to use one language as another, different, language. In C++ this pattern has its uses. You can accomplish the same things in C#, but using different techniques.

Maybe this will help you:

```
class Myclass
{
}

class ChildClass : MyClass
{
}

class MockComposite<T> where T : MyClass
{
    public MockComposite(T objectToTest) { ... }
}
```

Here, you can pass a any class that derives from `MyClass` into `CompositeTester<>`. The biggest difference between this and your code is that here you need to pass in real existing non-generic classes that inherit `MyClass`. You are trying to inherit generically which is not possible.

In C++ this is basically like doing:

```
class Myclass
{
};

class ChildClass : MyClass
{
};

template<typename T>
class MockComposite
{
public:
    MockComposite(const T& objectToTest) { ... }
};
```

C# generics might look a bit like C++ templates but it's an entirely different idea. While C++ templates let you do be very flexible almost to the point of being like macros, generics remain rather tight, type-wise. You cannot do anything with a generic type that you have not said it can do explicitly, hence generic constraints like `where T : MyClass`. By specifying that, `MockComposite.MockComposite` can use `T` as a `MyType`.

Comment: I want to be able to write an object with generic testing behaviour that I can use to test any object that is derived from one specific base-class object.

Comment: @SirYakalot: And why does this testing class need to derive from the class that needs to be tested?

Comment: I suppose it could be written in an entirely different way. I'm converting some code and was wondering if there was an equivalent.

Comment: @SirYakalot: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12162023/572644). Most likely, you will want to use composition.