# Inherit from generic type as interface

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I am attempting to do something similar to:

```
public interface IView<T> : T where T : class 
{ 
    T SomeParam {get;} 
}
```

So that i can later do

```
public class SomeView : IView<ISomeView> 
{
}
```

Is it possible to specify inheritance using generics in this way or do i have to go the long way round and explicitly specify both interfaces when defining the class and do:

```
public interface IView<T> 
{ 
    T SomeParam {get;} 
}
public class SomeView : IView<ISomeView>, ISomeView 
{
}
```

Comment: Looks a bit like what Eric Lippert talks about in his post [Curiouser and Curiouser](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx). Note that he does point out that it only sort-of works in C#.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890516/in-c-sharp-4-0-is-it-possible-to-derive-a-class-from-a-generic-type-parameter

Comment: Remove the `: T` in your interface declaration.

Comment: why? the : T is the entire point of the question...

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible, but your goal *may* be achievable with [conversion operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx). It seems that what you're trying to do is make it possible to pass an `IView<T>` as the `T` object which it contains. You could write a base class like this:

```
public abstract class ViewBase<T> {
    public abstract T SomeParam { get; }

    public static implicit operator T(ViewBase<T> view) {
        return view.SomeParam;
    }
}
```

Then, if you define a class like:

```
public class SomeView : ViewBase<ISomeView> { }
```

It can be accepted anywhere an `ISomeView` is expected:

```
ISomeView view = new SomeView();
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: It is not possible.  See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895363/generic-class-that-inherits-its-generic-type)

An Interface can't derive from a `class`.  However nothing prevent you from doing this:

```
public interface ISomeView
{
}

public interface IView<out T> where T:class 
{
    T SomeParam { get; }
}

public class SomeView:IView<ISomeView>
{
    public ISomeView SomeParam { get; set; }
}
```

Edit:

If you don't want to implement the `T SomeParam { get; }` each time you need to have an implementation, Does this would work?

```
public interface ISomeView
{
}

public abstract class BaseView<T> where T : class
{
    public T SomeParam { get; set; }
}

public class SomeView : BaseView<ISomeView>{
}
```

In both case this would work:

```
public class main
{
    public class OneOfThoseView : ISomeView
    {
    }

    public main()
    {
        OneOfThoseView oneOfThose = new OneOfThoseView();
        SomeView x = new SomeView();
        x.SomeParam = oneOfThose;
    }

}
```

Edit 2:
Not exactly what you want to do but this would force your SomeView class to return a `BaseView<SomeView>` class

```
public interface ISomeView
{
}

public abstract class BaseView<T> where T : BaseView<T>
{
    public T SomeParam { get; set; }
}

public class SomeView : BaseView<SomeView>
{
}
```

Now only this would work.

```
public main()
{
    SomeView y= new SomeView ();
    SomeView x = new SomeView();
    x.SomeParam = y;
}
```

Comment: As i said, this is something i am attempting to avoid. i would rather define as little as possible.

Comment: You want a base abstract class?