# Work around for deriving from a generic type parameter

Tags: c#, .net, generics, refactoring

I realize it is not possible to derive from a generic type parameter, and I understand all the complications that arise if it is allowed.

- [Generics FAQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479859.aspx#fundamentals_topic15)
- [Why it can't be done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842636/why-cannot-c-sharp-generics-derive-from-one-of-the-generic-type-parameters-like/1842855#1842855)

So my question is, how do I work around this? I am trying to eliminate some duplicate code and the best solution (which is not a solution because it cannot be done) I have come up with would be to do something like this:

```
public class Proxy<T> : T where T : CommonBaseClass
```

The reason I would want to do this is to override some methods in the `CommonBaseClass`.

Here is some actual code examples from my project:

```
public class ReportingServiceProxy : ReportingService2010
{
    protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse (WebRequest request)
    {
        WebResponse response = base.GetWebResponse(request);
        // Do override stuff here
        return response;
    }
}

public class ReportingExecutionProxy : ReportExecution2005
{
    protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse (WebRequest request)
    {
        WebResponse response = base.GetWebResponse(request);
        // Do override stuff here
        return response;
    }
}
```

In the example above the `ReportingService2010` & `ReportExecution2005` classes both derive from `SoapHttpClientProtocol` which derives from `HttpWebClientProtocol`. The override methods `GetWebResponse` and `GetWebRequest` both override methods in `HttpWebClientProtocol` and are identical. These methods are where the code duplication exists which I am trying to refactor out.

For completeness, here is some additional code where I implement the code above:

```
public abstract class SSRSReportBase<T> where T : new()
{        
    protected T ssrs;
    protected abstract void ServiceLogon();

    public SSRSReportBase()
    {
        ServiceLogon();
        // Do other common constructor work here.
    }
}

// Implementation #1
public class SSRSReportExecution : SSRSReportBase<ReportExecutionProxy>
{
    protected override void ServiceLogon()
    {
        ssrs.LogonUser("LoginName", null, null);
    }

    // Create additional wrapper methods for ReportExecution2005
}

// Implementation #2
public class SSRSReportingService : SSRSReportBase<ReportingServiceProxy>
{
    protected override void ServiceLogon()
    {
        ssrs.LogonUser("LoginName", null, null);
    }

    // Create additional wrapper methods for ReportingService2010
}
```

The only solution I have come up with is not a possible solution, so obviously it's NOT a solution. Here is the *bad* code:

```
public class ReportProxy<T> : T where T : HttpWebClientProtocol, new()
{
    protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse (WebRequest request)
    {
        WebResponse response = base.GetWebResponse(request);
        return response;
    }
}

// Implementation #1
public class SSRSReportExecution : SSRSReportBase<ReportProxy<ReportExecution2005>>
{
}

// Implementation #2
public class SSRSReportingService : SSRSReportBase<ReportProxy<ReportingService2010>>
{
}
```

**Question:** *So my question is, how can this code be refactored in such a way as to remove the duplicate code (the `GetWebRequest` and `GetWebResponse` overrides)?*

Comment: So, you're effectively wanting a wrapper around class (X, Y) so you can invoke one method and get the same effect for both X and Y? Maybe I've confused on what you want.

Comment: Can you consider composition rather than inheritance to achieve what you're trying to do? So that you will have a private instance of T that will get the call to GetWebResponse?

Comment: I was thinking that would be the optimal solution. Taking an internal `T` reference, such that you simply expose it's operations via method to the underlying `T` implementation.

Comment: I'm not sure composition would work. The calls to GetWebResponse/Request are not made in code I own/control. The ReportingService2010 and ReportExecution2005 classes are generated classes for web services which have been added to the VS project. It is in those classes that the calls are made. So by using inheritance I can change the base functionality of the two services without having to change the auto-generated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution would be to not use generics at all and to use a factory pattern. Instead of having a generic parameter with the `BaseClass` and the `new()` constraint. Type everything `BaseClass` and provide a factory for `new()`. This can be either a full-fleged factory class or a lightweight factory delegate.

```
public interface IProtocolFactory
{
    ProtocolBaseClass Create();
}

public class SomeDerivedProtocolFactory : IProtocolFactory
{
    public ProtocolBaseClass Create()
    {
        return new SomeDerivedProtocol();
    }
}
```

You might even add additional initialization code in the factory.

```
public class ReportProxy
{
    private IProtocolFactory _factory;

    public ReportProxy(IProtocolFactory factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        ProtocolBaseClass protocol = _factory.Create();
        ...
    }
}
```

Using a delegate

```
    private Func<ProtocolBaseClass> _createProtocol;

    public ReportProxy(Func<ProtocolBaseClass> createProtocol)
    {
        _createProtocol= createProtocol;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        ProtocolBaseClass protocol = _createProtocol();
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Thanks - This is pretty much what I did. I ended up ditching generics all together and using a factory pattern in conjunction with an interface & partial class for the services to describe the common behavior (the overrides). So, solution: Use partial classes & interfaces instead of generics.