# Can you extend a generic class in C#

Tags: c#, generics, extending

Let's say I have this class

```
public Holder<T> : IHolder
{
    private mystring;
    private myobj;

    public Holder(T obj, string str)
    {
        mystring = str;
        myobj = obj;
    }
}
```

Then I want to have Holder< T> extend T, so that I can use Holder< T> as I would a normal T.  Is there any way of doing this?

So for exampler, I would like Holder< int> to be treated like an int.

Just adding the : T doesn't work, but I was curious if there was another way.

Implicit conversions wouldn't work, as I would like it to be able to go in, for example an IEnumerable< int>

Comment: Try it and see (it's about 3 keystrokes and will work or result in an applicable error message). However, perhaps an *implicit conversion* to T would work?

Comment: What do you mean "Extend T"? Inherit it?

Comment: So you want Holder<int> to be treated as an int (for example)?

Comment: I think if it is an interface it would work fine.

Comment: You can't do `class Holder<T> : T`

Comment: Don't know if this is what you are after, but try out implicit conversions for the class, but that might be hard to do with a generic type.

Comment: It works in C++ so probably in C# like this `class Foo<T> : T`

Comment: What kind of relation is there between Holder and T? `Has a` or `is a`?

Comment: Answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842636/why-cannot-c-sharp-generics-derive-from-one-of-the-generic-type-parameters-like

Comment: @56ka C++ Templates are very different from C# generics.  C++ Templates replace the type _at compile tine_, while C# generics do so _at run time_.  It may seem subtle but it allows you to do more things with C++ templates (because they are built against specific types) that are not possible with Generics, since they must work against any type that meets the generic constraint(s)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way generics are implemented in .NET requires that all `Foo<T>` must behave largely the same way regardless of `T`.  Among other things, all `Foo<T>` must have the same members, save only for the fact that members may include `T` in their definitions.  If `Foo<T>` could inherit from `T`, knowing what members `Foo<T>` exposed would require knowing what members `T` exposed, which could of course be completely different for a `Foo<Automobile>` and a `Foo<Cat>`.  If one knows that `Foo<T>` will only be used for types that derive from e.g. `Animal`, one could define a `class Foo<T> : Animal where T:Animal`, but that would only allow a `Foo<Cat>` to be used as an `Animal`--not as a `Cat`.

In many cases, however, what is really needed is not a type `Foo<T>` which actually inherits `T`, but rather the ability to create an object which mostly behaves like `T`, but with some differences.  The .NET Framework doesn't allow that to be done directly either, but there are some libraries which can auto-generate proxy objects for that purpose.  Given an interface and one or more objects, each of which implements some interface members, and which collectively implement all of them, a proxy generator will create (at run time!) a new class which holds references to the supplied objects and implements that interface by creating for each interface method a class method that chains to the corresponding method on one of the passed-in objects.

Note that although the method which creates these new classes will be generic, the classes themselves will not be.  It may be that `myProxyMaker.Create<IFoo>(IFlyingMammal)` returns a `proxy8675309` and a `myProxyMaker.Create<ISwimmingMammal>` returns a `proxy24601`.  Because they are completely different classes, the fact that `IFlyingMammal` has different members from `ISwimmingMammal` would pose no problem.  The fact that the classes might have ugly machine-generated names wouldn't really matter because one wouldn't be declaring variables of type `proxy8675309` or `proxy24601`, but instead types `IFlyingMammal` and `ISwimmingMammal`.