# Generics Inheritance and conversion

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have the following classes:

```
class Item { }
class MeetingItem : Item { }
class ItemGroup<T> { }
```

now, this works without an issue:

```
Item something;
something = new MeetingItem();
```

this however fails:

```
ItemGroup<Item> itemGroup;
itemGroup = new ItemGroup<MeetingItem>(); // Fails here
```

I'm getting the "Cannot Implicitly convert type '`ItemGroup<MeetingItem>`' to '`ItemGroup<Item>`'" error.  Isn't that exactly what I'm doing above (assigning something to the type Item and then instantiating to MeetingItem)?

What I will have eventually is a collection of Items in the ItemGroup class along with a few other members.  And then I'm going to have a collection of ItemGroups that will contain different types of derived Items.  Ideally I'd like to have Item as an abstract class (maybe an interface, I might need to keep it a class depending on what I need to implement).

I'm open to any refactoring ideas.

Thanks.

Edit to add my solution without having a Generic ItemGroup:
I decided to ditch generics... kinda...  I cobbled together this:

```
public class ItemGroup {
  public Type ItemType => this.Items.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
  public IList Items { get; set; }

  public ItemGroup(Type itemType) {
    var genericListType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(itemType);
    Items = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(genericListType);
  }
}
```

So, I can now do something like this:

```
List<ItemGroup> groups = new List<ItemGroup>();
groups.Add(new ItemGroup(typeof(MeetingItem));
```

and then I can test for the specific Item type by the following:

```
groups[0].ItemType == typeof(MeetingItem)
```

It seems a little hacky, but it works.  I'm a little concerned about performance on the ItemType Property, and I'm open to any refactoring ideas.

Comment: You should take a look at covariance and contravariance: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx

Comment: Explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842636/why-cannot-c-sharp-generics-derive-from-one-of-the-generic-type-parameters-like

Comment: Just because two types, `A` and `B`, have a particular inheritance relationship, that doesn't mean that `G<A>` and `G<B>` have the *same* inheritance relationship.

Comment: Ok... Fair enough... I can't do that.  I get it now.  So, the question is, should I delete this question or leave it and have it redirect people to the duplicate? Or should I mark Luann's answer as the answer, or just leave it open?

Comment: I nominated to reopen this to put in my (hopefully) final answer.  It involves using a non generic class (ArrayList) that I inherited to my own class.  I think it'll work and might help others.  I'd like to keep the reference to the duplicate however as that will help others as well.

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue with variance.

Consider a simple interface like this:

```
interface MyInterface<T>
{
  T GetStuff();
  void SetStuff(T value);
}
```

Now, you have `MyInterface<A>`, and `MyInterface<B>`, where `B` inherits from `A`.

It's always safe to return `B` instead of `A`. However, it isn't safe to return `A` instead of `B`. Therefore, looking at `GetStuff`, it should be possible to cast `MyInterface<B>` to `MyInterface<A>`, but not vice versa.

It's always safe to pass `B` instead of `A`. However, it isn't safe to pass `A` instead of `B`. Therefore, looking at `SetStuff`, it should be possible to cast `MyInterface<A>` to `MyInterface<B>`, but not vice versa.

The problem should be obvious - you can't fulfill both at once. There is no safe cast for *both* of the methods.

If you can avoid having both ways in a single interface, you can use the `out`/`in` keywords to specify which kind of variance is supported by your interface, but that's it. Looking at classes from the .NET framework:

```
IEnumerable<object> enumerable = Enumerable.Empty<string>(); // Safe, 
                                                             // enumerable is covariant
ICollection<object> collection = new Collection<string>();   // Error, 
                                                             // collection isn't covariant

Func<object> func = () => "Hi!"; // Safe, Func<T> is covariant
Action<object> func = (string val) => { ... }; // Error, Action<T> isn't covariant
```

On the other hand, with contravariance:

```
Func<string> func = () => new object(); // Error, Func<T> isn't contravariant
Action<string> func = (object val) => { ... }; // Safe, Action<T> is contravariant
```