# Redundant generic constraint?

Tags: c#, generics, type-constraints

Consider the following generic method:

```
public T2 Frob<T1, T2>(T1 item)
        where T1 : class, T2
        => item as T2;
```

The compiler will refuse to compile this code; *The type parameter 'T2' cannot be used with the 'as' operator because it does not have a class type constraint nor a 'class' constraint*

Ok, this is easily solvable simply doing:

```
public T2 Frob<T1, T2>(T1 item)
        where T1 : class, T2
        where T2 : class
        => item as T2;
```

But isn't this redundant? Is there any possible `T2` that is not a `class` considering the constraints already in place for `T1`?

My question is not *why* this "inference" wasn't implemented in the compiler, the reason could simply be "no one thought about it" and thats OK. I'm more interested in knowing if my reasoning is correct in that `T2` is effectively and *in all cases* constrained to `class` in the first example even if its not explicitly enforced.

Comment: Why do you think the constraints for `T1` do also apply for `T2`? They have nothing in common, in particular whilst `T1` *derives* from `T2`, `T2` doesn´t know *anything* of `T1`.

Comment: Sure, but `T2` itself isn´t constrained to anything, it could be even a `struct`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere give me one example of a reference class deriving from a value type, because that is precisely what must happen with the constraints in place for `T1`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I think what OP means is that `T2` _cannot be a value type_ because `T1` cannot be derived from a value type. So it necessarily has to be a reference type.

Comment: Ah, okay, I see. Than I guess your reasoning is correct, however it is not implemented because of the allready mentioned fact.

Comment: @RenéVogt where is it derivying?

Comment: Personally I  find these questions "Primarily opinion based" but questions about "Why did the C# designers implement X in the compiler" have been answered before so... what do I know.

Comment: My two cents here is that it's just an use case that's not currently implemented in generics.

Comment: I mean, infering that  "T1 is class and derives T2, thus T2 is a reference type too"

Comment: @Jamiec If you read my question, I'm not asking *why* the compiler needs a redundant constraint. I'm asking if it *is* redundant or if there is some very strange corner case where it wouldn't be so. I can't think of any but I'd like to be 100% sure.

Comment: Although this question is nice and shows research-affords I can´t see any way answering it except simply saying: yes, your reasoning is correct, however the behaviour you want assumes reverse constraining which isn´t implemented.

Comment: One way or another, you're asking why a human being implemented it that way, or whether said human made an oversight. That's a question of motivation, and the only person who could answer it is the human who implemented it.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: Well, that's a good answer for a good question, isn't it?

Answer (score 4):

My interpretation of this, given the C# 5.0 specs say at 7.10.11, The `as` operator:

> In an operation of the form `E as T`, `E` must be an expression and `T` must be a reference type, **a type parameter known to be a reference type**, or a nullable type.

The compiler at that point only considers `T2` in this block:

```
public T2 Frob<T1, T2>(T1 item)
        where T1 : class, T2
        => item as T2;
```

And it sees that `T2` itself is not constrained. Sure, it could *deduct* that in this case `T1` is expected to be a reference type *and* inherit `T2`, therefore that `T2` itself should also be a reference type, but I'm sure there are reasons for not doing that.

Comment: Actually there probably *aren't* reasons for doing it other than what Eric Lippert notes in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1843557. TL;DR: "Features take time to implement."