# How to use the "where" keyword in C# with a generic interface, and inheritance

Tags: c#, .net

What I want to achieve is this:

- Declare a generic class (<T>),
- Have the "T" restricted to types that implement IMySpecialInterface<X> (where "X" is not a known type),
- And have the class inherit from a parent class.

to give an incorrect example:

```
public class MyClass<T> : MyParentClass where T : IMySpecialInterface<X>
{
...
}
```

What is the proper syntax to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't use generics without knowing the types, unless you created the type at runtime.

Your best fit would be:

```
public class MyClass<T, U> : MyParentClass where T: IMySpecialInterface<U>
{

}
```

**UPDATE** or could you potentially use `dynamic`?

Comment: this doesn't achieve the requirements. X isn't known when creating the class.

Comment: Then he can't do it, unless he dynamically creates the type at runtime.  The compiler can't compile unknowns.

Comment: that's why you need a non-generic version of the interface, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419176/how-to-use-the-where-keyword-in-c-with-a-generic-interface-and-inheritance/3419199#3419199) ;)

Answer (score 8):

You will need to define a non-generic version of `IMySpecialInterface<X>`, unless you supply a secondary type for `MyClass`. The whole thing would look like this then:

```
public interface IMySpecialInterface
{
}

public interface IMySpecialInterface<X> : IMySpecialInterface
{
}

public MyClass<T> : MyParentClass where T : IMySpecialInterface
{
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
public class MyClass<T, X> : MyParentClass where T : IMySpecialInterface<X>
{
...
}
```

Comment: this doesn't achieve the requirements. X isn't known when creating the class.