# Compile error when creating instance of object with generic type interface

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, casting, covariance

I have an interface that receives a generic type, let's call it IFoo. That generic type is constrained to being implemented by a different interface, IBar. These two interfaces are defined as follows:

```
internal interface IFoo<out TBar> where TBar : IBar
{
}

internal interface IBar
{
}
```

I then created two classes, each implementing the interfaces created above:

```
internal class SpecificFoo : IFoo<SpecificBar>
{
}

internal class SpecificBar : IBar
{
}
```

Everything works fine, and instanciating a SpecificFoo does not generate any compile error, since covariance was used when defining the generic type IBar.

```
// No compile error and instantiation works!
IFoo<IBar> correctFoo = new SpecificFoo();
```

Since I always use the interface IFoo with the interface IBar to store new instances of derived classes, my code has variables with type IFoo scattered all over. To simplify this definition, I created a second variation for the IFoo interface:

```
internal interface IFoo : IFoo<IBar>
{
}
```

The problem is that now the instanciation of new objects is not working as previously.

```
// Compile error!!
IFoo incorrectFoo = new SpecificFoo();

// Cast error!!
IFoo alsoIncorrectFoo = (IFoo)new SpecificFoo();
```

Why is the compiler not "smart" enough to understand that IFoo or IFoo with generic type IBar are the same thing? And why does the cast not work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748706/generic-inheritance-in-c

Comment: `IFoo` and `IFoo<IBar>` are not the same thing. `IFoo` is a subtype of `IFoo<IBar>`, so an `IFoo` is a `IFoo<IBar>`, but an `IFoo<IBar>` is not necessarily an `IFoo`.

Comment: @Luke Woodward although an IFoo<IBar> is not directly related to an IFoo, like the other way around is, since I am constraining TBar to implement an IBar, I assumed they should be the same thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding the problem, you will need to make `SpecificFoo` implement `IFoo`

```
internal class SpecificFoo : IFoo<SpecificBar>, IFoo
{ .. }
```

Which would allow you to

```
IFoo correctFoo = new SpecificFoo();
//and
IFoo<IBar> anotherFoo = correctFoo;
```

Comment: Yes, that works! Thanks a lot! It makes sense, there needs to be  direct relation between SpecificFoo and IFoo, because an IFoo<IBar> is not necessarily an IFoo, like @Luke Woodward said